# Is there a tool to check CSS url files exist?

Tags: css

I've just been tasked with migrating a website from a Windows server to a Linux server.

One of the issues I've noticed straight away is that there are a number of CSS url() definitions that don't work because the case in the CSS is not the same as the actual file.

eg:

```
background: url(myFile.jpg);
```

while on the server the file is actually MyFile.jpg.

Does anyone know of a simple tool or browser plugin I can use just to scan the CSS file and verify that the url() declarations exist so that I can easily find and fix them?

The site is quite large, so I don't want to have to navigate through the pages to find 404 errors if I can avoid it.

Comment: Be aware that filenames in linux are case sensitive !
That is always the main isues from migrating from win to linux

Comment: Just open page in a browser and see errors at network section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the  [W3c Link Checker](http://validator.w3.org/checklink) also scans CSS files which is very handy.

Had this have not worked I would have had to put together something like Vanga's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use Developer Tools in Google Chrome or Firebug in Firefox.

When you load HTML page with that CSS, it will show any missing resources in Network tab.

**EDIT**

I guess there is no any tool that will

1. Scan through CSS file for all the URLs
2. Check whether each URL exists or not.

But you can try following two links for these two tasks.

1. [RegEx to get the URLs from CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652777/java-regex-to-get-the-urls-from-css) : With this you will have all list of URLs used in CSS
2. [Check if a URL exists or not with cURL](http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2009/05/php-check-if-a-url-exists-with-curl/) : An example in PHP was given.

You can still search for these two items separately and try fixing the issues.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: That's what I did initially, but the site is quite large. I've updated my question to explain this.

Comment: Added more details to my answer. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

What, if you simply write a http request into browser's URL bar pointing directly to the image and/or css?

Answer (score 0):

How about `firebug` in firefox? It would give you all 404 in its console.
[download](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/firebug/)

Answer (score 0):

You can install Firebug if you're using Firefox or you can press F12 if you're using Chrome.. i think that goes the same with IE.. From there you will be able to check the URL and even view it in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would approach this.

1. Make sure all image requests are handled by a (PHP) script, by adding the following to my .htaccess

   RewriteRule .(?:jpe?g|gif|png|bmp)$ /images.php [NC,L]
2. Use file_exists() to check if the file exists, maybe even try if a lowercase version of the file exists.
3. Log missing files into a database table or text file.
4. Use a script to loop through the website's sitemap with curl to get a complete list of requested filenames that resulted in a 404.