# Not able to take screenShot using HtmlUnitDriver [Selenium WebDriver java]

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit-driver

I am wanting to take a screenshot of a page using HtmlUnitDriver I came across this [Link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/selenium-developers/PTR_j4xLVRM/k2yVq01Fa7oJ) where this guy has made a custom HTML unit driver to take the screenshot.
But unfortunately, while implementing that I am getting an exception.

**"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.io.File
    at Test.main(Test.java:39)"**

My code is as follows-

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;

public class Test extends ScreenCaptureHtmlUnitDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        WebDriver driver = new ScreenCaptureHtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl");
        try{
        File scrFile = ((ScreenCaptureHtmlUnitDriver) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("D:\\TEMP.PNG"));
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

HtmlUnit driver which I am using(the one which is in the link) is this-

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.internal.Base64Encoder;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebRequest;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebWindow;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class ScreenCaptureHtmlUnitDriver extends HtmlUnitDriver implements TakesScreenshot {

private static Map<String, byte[]> imagesCache = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, byte[]>());

private static Map<String, String> cssjsCache = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, String>());

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652777/java-regex-to-get-the-urls-from-css
private final static Pattern cssUrlPattern = Pattern.compile("background(-image)?[\\s]*:[^url]*url[\\s]*\\([\\s]*([^\\)]*)[\\s]*\\)[\\s]*");// ?<url>

public ScreenCaptureHtmlUnitDriver() {
    super();
}

public ScreenCaptureHtmlUnitDriver(boolean enableJavascript) {
    super(enableJavascript);
}

public ScreenCaptureHtmlUnitDriver(Capabilities capabilities) {
    super(capabilities);
}

public ScreenCaptureHtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion version) {
    super(version);
    DesiredCapabilities var = ((DesiredCapabilities) getCapabilities());
    var.setCapability(CapabilityType.TAKES_SCREENSHOT, true);
}

//@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <X> X getScreenshotAs(OutputType<X> target) throws WebDriverException {
    byte[] archive = new byte[0];
    try {
        archive = downloadCssAndImages(getWebClient(), (HtmlPage) getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    if(target.equals(OutputType.BASE64)){
        return target.convertFromBase64Png(new Base64Encoder().encode(archive));
    }
    if(target.equals(OutputType.BYTES)){
        return (X) archive;
    }
    return (X) archive;
}

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244272/how-can-i-tell-htmlunits-webclient-to-download-images-and-css
protected byte[] downloadCssAndImages(WebClient webClient, HtmlPage page) throws Exception {
    WebWindow currentWindow = webClient.getCurrentWindow();
    Map<String, String> urlMapping = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, byte[]> files = new HashMap<String, byte[]>();
    WebWindow window = null;
    try {
        window = webClient.getWebWindowByName(page.getUrl().toString()+"_screenshot");
        webClient.getPage(window, new WebRequest(page.getUrl()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        window = webClient.openWindow(page.getUrl(), page.getUrl().toString()+"_screenshot");
    }

    String xPathExpression = "//*[name() = 'img' or name() = 'link' and (@type = 'text/css' or @type = 'image/x-icon') or  @type = 'text/javascript']";
    List<?> resultList = page.getByXPath(xPathExpression);

    Iterator<?> i = resultList.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        try {
            HtmlElement el = (HtmlElement) i.next();
            String resourceSourcePath = el.getAttribute("src").equals("") ? el.getAttribute("href") : el
                    .getAttribute("src");
            if (resourceSourcePath == null || resourceSourcePath.equals(""))
                continue;
            URL resourceRemoteLink = page.getFullyQualifiedUrl(resourceSourcePath);
            String resourceLocalPath = mapLocalUrl(page, resourceRemoteLink, resourceSourcePath, urlMapping);
            urlMapping.put(resourceSourcePath, resourceLocalPath);
            if (!resourceRemoteLink.toString().endsWith(".css")) {
                byte[] image = downloadImage(webClient, window,  resourceRemoteLink);
                files.put(resourceLocalPath, image);
            } else {
                String css = downloadCss(webClient, window, resourceRemoteLink);
                for (String cssImagePath : getLinksFromCss(css)) {
                    URL cssImagelink = page.getFullyQualifiedUrl(cssImagePath.replace("\"", "").replace("\'", "")
                            .replace(" ", ""));
                    String cssImageLocalPath = mapLocalUrl(page, cssImagelink, cssImagePath, urlMapping);
                    files.put(cssImageLocalPath, downloadImage(webClient, window, cssImagelink));
                }
                files.put(resourceLocalPath, replaceRemoteUrlsWithLocal(css, urlMapping)
                        .replace("resources/", "./").getBytes());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    String pagesrc =  replaceRemoteUrlsWithLocal(page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString(), urlMapping);
    files.put("page.html", pagesrc.getBytes());
    webClient.setCurrentWindow(currentWindow);
    return createZip(files);
}

String downloadCss(WebClient webClient, WebWindow window, URL resourceUrl) throws Exception {
    if (cssjsCache.get(resourceUrl.toString()) == null) {
        cssjsCache.put(resourceUrl.toString(), webClient.getPage(window, new  WebRequest(resourceUrl))
                .getWebResponse().getContentAsString());

    }
    return cssjsCache.get(resourceUrl.toString());
}

byte[] downloadImage(WebClient webClient, WebWindow window, URL resourceUrl)  throws Exception {
    if (imagesCache.get(resourceUrl.toString()) == null) {
        imagesCache.put(
                resourceUrl.toString(),
                IOUtils.toByteArray(webClient.getPage(window, new  WebRequest(resourceUrl)).getWebResponse()
                        .getContentAsStream()));
    }
    return imagesCache.get(resourceUrl.toString());
}

 public static byte[] createZip(Map<String, byte[]> files) throws IOException      {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ZipOutputStream zipfile = new ZipOutputStream(bos);
    Iterator<String> i = files.keySet().iterator();
    String fileName = null;
    ZipEntry zipentry = null;
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        fileName = i.next();
        zipentry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
        zipfile.putNextEntry(zipentry);
        zipfile.write(files.get(fileName));
    }
    zipfile.close();
    return bos.toByteArray();
}

    List<String> getLinksFromCss(String css) {
    List<String> result = new LinkedList<String>();
    Matcher m = cssUrlPattern.matcher(css);
    while (m.find()) { // find next match
        result.add( m.group(2));
    }
    return result;
}

 String replaceRemoteUrlsWithLocal(String source, Map<String, String>  replacement) {
    for (String object : replacement.keySet()) {
        // background:url(http://org.com/images/image.gif)
        source = source.replace(object, replacement.get(object));
    }
    return source;
}

String mapLocalUrl(HtmlPage page, URL link, String path, Map<String, String>  replacementToAdd) throws Exception {
    String resultingFileName = "resources/" +    FilenameUtils.getName(link.getFile());
    replacementToAdd.put(path, resultingFileName);
    return resultingFileName;
}

}
```

**UPDATE**

Code provided by Andrew works- but I wanted to know if there is a way by which we can download only selected resources. For eg [this](http://www.irctc.co.in) website I would like to download only captcha image those id is "//*[@id='cimage']" because downloading all the resources will take a long time. Is there a way by which we can download only the specific resource. Because with the existing code provided
below all the resources get downloaded.

```
byte[] zipFileBytes = ((ScreenCaptureHtmlUnitDriver) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("D:\\TEMP.PNG"), zipFileBytes);
```

Comment: Can you add the full exception stack and tell the type of "B" ?

Comment: Hi Florent I edited the code and added try catch with printstacktrace but I am still getting "java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.io.File
 at Test.main(Test.java:19)" as stacktrace

Comment: Hi is it necessary to use HtmlUnitDriver if not plz go for Phantom js its better in terms when talking screenshot

Comment: I am not familiar with phantom js! can we use phantom js with selenium web driver? because the above code is just a part of the larger code where I am trying to take a screenshot of a web page via headless browser

Comment: The reason I am wanting to use Html unit driver is coz of its speed. Although phantom.js is also quick than chrome and firefox but it is not as fast as HtmlUnit driver!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says that the code is trying to convert a `byte[]` to a `File`. It's easy to see why if you just strip out the unused paths from `getScreenshotAs`:

```
public <X> X getScreenshotAs(OutputType<X> target) throws WebDriverException {
    byte[] archive = new byte[0];
    try {
        archive = downloadCssAndImages(getWebClient(), (HtmlPage) getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return (X) archive;
}
```

There's no way you can get a `File` out of that. `OutputType.FILE` is not supported, so you have to handle file output yourself. Luckily, that's easy. You can change your code to:

```
byte[] zipFileBytes = ((ScreenCaptureHtmlUnitDriver) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("D:\\TEMP.PNG"), zipFileBytes);
```

See [FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeByteArrayToFile(java.io.File,%20byte[]))() for more.

Comment: Thank you so much, Andrew, that works great :) I have added some more detail to my question can you please have a look! Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score -3):

Check this out this may helpful for you

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:/Users/home/Desktop/screenshot.png"));// copy it somewhere
```

Comment: This doesn't explain / deal with the actual error message, misunderstands the question and what OP is trying to achieve, and will replace one error with another.

Comment: This is the easiest way to take screen shot of CURRENT webpage

Comment: That wasn't the question. OP wants to know how to get past *"ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.io.File"* in a customised version of HtmlUnitDriver, which ordinarily can't take screenshots at all.